# No user and password boxes when trying to login to Magento 2 admin

Tags: admin, magento2.3.0, admin-login

After successfully installing **Magento 2.3.0**, I tried to **login** to the **admin panel** for the first time.
The background color of the page that came up is grey like the Magento page, but it was a **blank page**. The **User and Password** fields don't appear.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling 4 times. 
I am using WAMP on windows 10.

How do I get my login fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Developer mode

**Using Command**: `php bin/Magento deploy:mode:set developer`

**Using Manually**:  Change **default** to **developer** in `<installation_dir>app/etc/env.php`.

```
<?php
return [
    ......
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    ......
]
```

2. Enable display_errors in `app/bootstrap.php`  by uncomment as below

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I changed to developer mode and uncommented the ini_set.
I then cleared my browser's cache.

When I tried to open my admin login page I got the following:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp64/www/nisuhon/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'

The message goes on.
How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure require_js.phtml exists in Magento_Backend module(view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml). Folder name and file names should be case sensitive.

Comment: It exists there

Answer (score 0):

check the following file,

> vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
>   Than Line 139

if (0 === strpos($path, $directory)) {

[Invalid template file:in Magento 2.2.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254801/invalid-template-filein-magento-2-2-7)

Comment: I now get:
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\wamp64\www\nisuhon\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 6

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes this issue come because of space in PHP start tag of controller facing same issue just removed whitespace in:

<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
removing the space resolved my error            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433086/fatal-error-namespace-declaration-statement-has-to-be-the-very-first-statement

Comment: I tried removing all whitespaces manually and also used codebeautify.org
I still get the same error as before, it just says line 1 instead of line 6.

Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in C:\wamp64\www\nisuhon\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 1

Can't understand where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Even when there is nothing before the Namespace declaration I get the same error:
<?php namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File;